# How to put marker in Android GraphView

Tags: android, graph, marker

This question is specific to the opensource GraphView library. (https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView)

Have someone used it to add marker in it?

I want to create a realtime ECG graph with it. And need to create a vertical line when user press a button. I like the GraphView library as its simple and support realtime continuous stream of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue, here is the trick.

- Add an other series,
  add two points (x, min_y_value) and (x, max_y_value) ... where x is the horizontal position where you want to add marker.

obviously it include some handling as line is continuous graph.. when I was using continuous graph.. I was running that marker line on top of my graph i.e (x, max_y_value) and when ever i need to draw marker, I pull it down like (x, min_y_value) then pull back up in straight line with same x value (x, max_y_value).. obviously there will be a visible line on top of graph that you can hide by some overlay.

Answer (score 3):

this is not possible out of the box.

You should have a look into the source code of Graphview (https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView). The code is really simple.

Take a look to the method `onDraw()` of `GraphView.java`. There you should be able to draw lines...

Comment: oops didn't notice, its the author who responded :-)

hey btw, I created an ECG graph (that runs in ECG graph fashion.. i.e. draw a series from start to end.. then overwrite another series on top of it.. (keep removing the older one). How can I contribute back to the project? 
Though right now code is not generic.. and i m not using a class.. but sounds I can convert my logic into some generic class by extending your GraphView.

Comment: :) every good (well documented and generic) pull request on github is welcome.

Comment: You probably mean Push request? :)
Hey I m having strange problem. 
1st: It was not updating the real time graph on ICS / JellyBeans... then I set my target SDK to level 10 and it worked.

Now: Sometimes It doesn't update!! I noticed it once on Nexus 7 Tablet, but Its happening all the time on my Xperia S (Android 4.0.4).. Nexus 7 looks fine. I tried invalidating graphView manually... but didn't work.
Though if I do LINEAR_LAYOUT.REMOVE_VIEW(GRAPHVIEW); then add GraphView again in that LinearLayout.. it updates :) obviously not right way. Can you tell me more whats issue with ICS?